# refresh a dynamic web page in python loop

Tags: python, html

I am trying to scrape a continuous series of image on a weblink which updates every 3 seconds, using a python script. Relevant excerpt of the code:

```
import urllib
import time

for i in range(5):
    cam_img = urllib.urlopen(my_url).read()
    ctr += 1
    f_name = "img" + str(ctr) +".jpg"
    f_hand = open(f_name, 'w')
    f_hand.write(cam_img)
    f_hand.close()
    time.sleep(3)
    urllib.urlcleanup()
```

The above script works on the first image, but subsequent images are the same..i.e. it does not reload the page. The url I use in the code here is the http link of the image file which I got from html source of another http page which displays these images as a camera stream. When I manually refresh the link of that image, i see a different image every 3 seconds. Instead of the url link of the image file should I use some other approach?

Comment: I think it really depends on *how* it `displays these images as a camera stream`.  Are you sure the page you got this from is using the same image url each time, and even if it is, it could be sending a signal to the camera to take a new picture in between images (which your code isn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have in mind:

**1.** Make sure it's the exact same url which feeds you different images every 3 seconds.

**2.** What you got from that url might be cache, it really depends on how the server handles your request, you can try to pass a "fake" parameter in your get request to see if you can bypass it, e.g. if the url is `http://example.com/example.jpg`, append a parameter in the end `http://example.com/example.jpg?s=`, normally this would force the server to feed you the actual content instead of cache.

Comment: Shane, thanks very much. That simple addition of the parameter worked!

Comment: Glad I helped : )